# Animated Vector Drawable not working with API 15

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-vectordrawable

I've been trying to run an Animated Vector Drawable on a device with API level 15.

The following is my animated vector "animated_feedback.xml":

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/feedback">

    <target
    android:animation="@animator/background_circle_animator"
    android:name="BG_White_Circle"/>

</animated-vector>
```

The drawable "feedback.xml" contains the following:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="180dp"
        android:viewportWidth="180"
        android:viewportHeight="180">
    <group
        android:name="BG_White_Circle_Group">
        <path
            android:name="BG_White_Circle"
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:pathData="M 90 0 C 139.705627485 0 180 40.2943725152 180 90 C 180 139.705627485 139.705627485 180 90 180 C 40.2943725152 180 0 139.705627485 0 90 C 0 40.2943725152 40.2943725152 0 90 0 Z" />
        <path
            android:name="Ring"
            android:strokeColor="#0094c1"
            android:strokeWidth="5.00000003634922"
            android:strokeMiterLimit="10"
            android:pathData="M 90 9 C 134.735064736 9 171 45.2649352637 171 90 C 171 134.735064736 134.735064736 171 90 171 C 45.2649352637 171 9 134.735064736 9 90 C 9 45.2649352637 45.2649352637 9 90 9 Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

And one of the animators "background_circle_animator.xml" is the following:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ordering="sequentially"
     android:fillAfter="true">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0f"
        android:valueTo="1f"
        android:duration="200"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="700"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1f"
        android:valueTo="0f"
        android:duration="200"/>

</set>
```

In my activity_main.xml I have the ImageView that should play this animation:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/feedback_ui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Finally in my MainActivity.java I have the following code:

```
ImageView feedbackUI = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feedback_ui);
feedbackUI.setImageResource(R.drawable.animated_feedback);

Drawable animation = feedbackUI.getDrawable();
if (animation instanceof Animatable) {
    feedbackUI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Animatable) animation).start();
}
```

The following is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "karim.com.testinganimation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

When running this code you should see a white circle with a blue ring on top of it and it should fade in and then fade out.

I ran this code on API > 21 device and it ran perfectly.

When I run it on a device with API 15 I get the following crash as soon as I the animation starts:

```
D/PropertyValuesHolder(19300): Can't find native method using JNI, use reflectionjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='set' signature='(F)V' in class Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath;
E/PropertyValuesHolder(19300): Couldn't find setter/getter for property null with value type float
E/PropertyValuesHolder(19300): Couldn't find no-arg method for property null: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: get []
D/AndroidRuntime(19300): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(19300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9e1f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19300): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setupSetterAndGetter(PropertyValuesHolder.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:392)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:934)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:957)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.startIfReady(AnimatorSet.java:705)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:659)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1040)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$900(ValueAnimator.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.handleMessage(ValueAnimator.java:675)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(19300):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  164):   Force finishing activity karim.com.testinganimation/.MainActivity
```

How can I fix this issue as it is very critical to run on devices with API level 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an API 15 device or emulator to test this, but it seems to me it's not happy with your middle objectAnimator:

```
 <objectAnimator
    android:duration="700"/>
```

Parts of your error message such as 'Couldn't find setter/getter for property null' suggest it's trying to set up an animator, but as there are no details of what the animator should be animating, it's crashing.

Assuming the purpose of this objectAnimator is just to cause the animated vector to pause before fading out, I would suggest trying something like this:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="1f"
    android:valueTo="1f"
    android:duration="700"/>
```