# invalid drawable tag animated-vector

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-vectordrawable

I've looked all over stackoverflow and no question was able to solve my problem.

I'm trying to play an animated vector drawable on a device with API 15 but I keep getting the following runtime exception:

```
    com.karim.test E/AvdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <animated-vector>
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-ldpi-v4/feedback.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f020066
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2152)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:906)
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:408)
at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:356)
at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:162)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$AvdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:905)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:356)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:428)
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:210)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2134)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:906) 
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:408) 
at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:356) 
at android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.java:162) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$AvdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:905) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:356) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71) 
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:428) 
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:210)

    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/animated_feedback_left.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020065
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:422)
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:204)

    Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag animated-vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:863)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664) 
at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45) 
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71) 
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:422)
at com.karim.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:204)
```

I'm using the same resources from my previous question that you can find over here [Animated Vector Drawable not working with API 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493335/animated-vector-drawable-not-working-with-api-15)

Also I've tested instead of using ImageView to use AppCompatImageView but still same error.

I've been debugging this error and it fails on the following statement:

```
final XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(resId);
```

inside:

```
public static VectorDrawableCompat create(@NonNull Resources res, @DrawableRes int resId, @Nullable Theme theme)
```

method of VectorDrawableCompat verion 23.3.0.

It seems that I'm having an issue with compatibility. At some point Android decides to use the XML parsing of API 15 instead of using the compat version. Any ideas on how I can solve this annoying problem?

**Update:**
I followed [Chris Banes](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.mph1j3n65) blog and still no luck. Basically I've updated the compat libraries to 23.4.0 and I used the following in my activity:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromSourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: The thing that catches my eye in your error is "feedback.png". That suggests to me that the problem is Android Studio converting the VectorDrawable to a .png then that causing the failure(can't animate a png!).  In your previous question you had the appropriate line in your gradle file to stop this conversion (vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true). make sure that's still there and hasn't accidentally been removed, and also try running Clean and Rebuild on your project to flush out any automatically generated files.

Comment: thanks @LewisMcGeary for the comment. It worked, after banging my head for a whole day and before giving up. So I had all my resources in a module that is linked to the main app. When I moved the animation related XMLs back to the main app, loading worked out fine and I was able to play the animation. I'm still trying to make sense out of it because why should it work if I have the resources in the main app and not part of a module. Will post an update once I have a answer.

Comment: Odd, but at least it's working! I've seen people post about problems resulting from a resource in their app having the same name as a resource in a library. Not sure if it's related, but if you work it out, do share!

Comment: @LewisMcGeary you could post the `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` as the answer to this particular question. Because it seems exactly that problem and this line solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image: API 16 animation]
**Inflating Drawable's**

`` `VectorDrawable` `` and `` `AnimatedVectorDrawable` `` in this support library can be inflated in this way:

- Calling static `getDrawable()` methods:

```
//This will only inflate a drawable with <vector> as the root element
VectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_vector);

//This will only inflate a drawable with <animated-vector> as the root element
AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_arrow_to_menu_animated_vector);

// This will inflate any drawable and will auto-fallback to the lollipop implementation on api 21+ devices
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.any_drawable);
```

*If inflating the Drawable in java code, it is recommended to always use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` as this handles Lollipop fallback when applicable. This allows the system to cache Drawable ConstantState and hence is more efficient.*
The library has the following morph (bi-directional) animations :

Play-Pause morph animation

Play-Stop morph animation

Arrow-Hamburger menu morph animation

As you can see, I produced the above image on my `API 16` phone:

```
import com.wnafee.vector.compat.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
mdrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) AnimatedVectorDrawable.getDrawable(this.getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.consolidated_animated_vector);
```

Look at the github **README** for `vector-compat` here: https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
This will fix your problem (down to `API 14`) if you merge it with your app module's `build.gradle` `dependencies` (usually at the end of file):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//Trying to FIX Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag animated-vector
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'//*******holy grail *******https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat
//  Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
//not needed
//  compile 'com.android.support:support-animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is support library 25.4.0 and it's intended to solve all our problems. For example it finally supports path morphing!

To use it add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

inside your project gradle file, and accordingly dependency itself:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
```

After that you can use vector drawable animation with path morphing (which is often the culprit behind "invalid drawable tag animated-vector") in below manner (a little Kotlin code):

```
val drawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.vector_drawable)
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable) // You may use usual ImageView class, no Compat necessary.
drawable.start()
```